# IntPtr arithmetics

Tags: c#, marshalling, intptr

I tried to allocate an array of structs in this way:

```
struct T {
    int a; int b;
}

data = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count*Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
...
```

I'd like to access to allocated data "binding" a struct to each element in array allocated
with AllocHGlobal... something like this

```
T v;
v = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data+1, typeof(T));
```

but i don't find any convenient way... **why IntPtr lack of arithmetics**? How can I workaround this in a "safe" way?

Someone could confirm that PtrToStructure function copy data into the struct variable? In other words, modifing the struct reflect modifications in the structure array data, or not?

Definitely, I want to operate on data pointed by an IntPtr using struct, without copying data each time, avoiding unsafe code.

Thank all!

Comment: PtrToStructure copies data. If you find yourself having to do this kind of stuff, write an unmanaged library and p/invoke it.

Comment: Maybe you want to explain why you want to work with an array of values in unmanaged memory to start with.  You can create a managed array and marshal it back and forth to unmanaged code.  Also you say "safe", but does that mean that code marked unsafe is out of the question, or do you just mean that you don't want to make mistakes?

Comment: I'm implementing buffer object abstraction for OpenGL. Data allocated could contains vertices, normals... I though to allocate memory using AllocHGlobal and manage data layout, but without giving up the semanthic offered by my implementation.

An example is glVertexPointer: it takes a buffer address and information about the memory layout. Could I convert T[] to IntPtr without copying data (using array memory directly thru IntPt)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have four options that I can think of, two using only "safe" code, and two using unsafe code.  The unsafe options are likely to be significantly faster.

#### Safe:

- Allocate your array in managed memory, and declare your P/Invoke function to take the array. i.e., instead of:

  ```
  [DllImport(...)]
  static extern bool Foo(int count, IntPtr arrayPtr);
  ```

  make it

  ```
  [DllImport(...)]
  static extern bool Foo(int count, NativeType[] array);
  ```

  (I've used `NativeType` for your struct name instead of `T`, since `T` is often used in a generic context.)

  The problem with this approach is that, as I understand it, the `NativeType[]` array will be marshaled twice for every call to `Foo`.  It will be copied from managed memory to unmanaged 
  memory before the call, and copied from unmanaged memory to managed memory afterward.  It can be improved, though, if `Foo` will only read from or write to the array.  In this case, decorate the `tarray` parameter with an `[In]` (read only) or `[Out]` (write only) attribute.  This allows the runtime to skip one of the copying steps.
- As you're doing now, allocate the array in unmanaged memory, and use a bunch of calls to `Marshal.PtrToStructure` and `Marshal.StructureToPtr`.  This will likely perform even worse than the first option, as you still need to copy elements of the array back and forth, and you're doing it in steps, so you have more overhead.  On the other hand, if you have many elements in the array, but you only access a small number of them in between calls to `Foo`, then this may perform better.  You might want a couple of little helper functions, like so:

  ```
  static T ReadFromArray<T>(IntPtr arrayPtr, int index){
      // below, if you **know** you'll be on a 32-bit platform,
      // you can change ToInt64() to ToInt32().
      return (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)(arrayPtr.ToInt64() +
          index * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));
  }
  // you might change `T value` below to `ref T value` to avoid one more copy
  static void WriteToArray<T>(IntPtr arrayPtr, int index, T value){
      // below, if you **know** you'll be on a 32-bit platform,
      // you can change ToInt64() to ToInt32().
      Marshal.StructureToPtr(value, (IntPtr)(arrayPtr.ToInt64() +
          index * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)), false);
  }
  ```

#### Unsafe:

- Allocate your array in unmanaged memory, and use pointers to access the elements.  This means that all the code that uses the array must be within an `unsafe` block.

  ```
  IntPtr arrayPtr = Marhsal.AllocHGlobal(count * sizeof(typeof(NativeType)));
  unsafe{
      NativeType* ptr = (NativeType*)arrayPtr.ToPointer();

      ptr[0].Member1 = foo;
      ptr[1].Member2 = bar;
      /* and so on */
  }
  Foo(count, arrayPtr);
  ```
- Allocate your array in managed memory, and pin it when you need to call the native routine:

  ```
  NativeType[] array = new NativeType[count];
  array[0].Member1 = foo;
  array[1].Member2 = bar;
  /* and so on */

  unsafe{
      fixed(NativeType* ptr = array)
          Foo(count, (IntPtr)ptr);
          // or just Foo(count, ptr), if Foo is declare as such:
          //     static unsafe bool Foo(int count, NativeType* arrayPtr);
  }
  ```

This last option is probably the cleanest if you can use unsafe code and are concerned about performance, because your only unsafe code is where you call the native routine.  If performance isn't an issue (perhaps if the size of the array is relatively small), or if you can't use unsafe code (perhaps you don't have full trust), then the first option is likely cleanest, although, as I mentioned, if the number of elements you'll access in between calls to the native routine are a small percentage of the number of elements within the array, then the second option is faster.

### Note:

The unsafe operations assume that your struct is [blittable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blittable_types).  If not, then the safe routines are your only option.

Answer (score 8):

> "Why `IntPtr` lack of arithmetics?"

`IntPtr` stores just a memory address. It doesn't have any kind of information about the contents of that memory location. In this manner, it's similar to `void*`. To enable pointer arithmetic you have to know the size of the object pointed to.

---

Fundamentally, `IntPtr` is primarily designed to be used in managed contexts as an opaque handle (i.e. one that you don't directly dereference in managed code and you just keep around to pass to unmanaged code.) `unsafe` context provides pointers you can manipulate directly.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the `IntPtr` type does not have its own arithmetic operators. Proper (unsafe) pointer arithmetic *is* supported in C#, but `IntPtr` and the `Marshal` class exist for 'safer' usage of pointers.

I think you want something like the following:

```
int index = 1; // 2nd element of array
var v = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(data.ToInt32() + 
    index * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)), typeof(T));
```

Also, note that `IntPtr` has no implicit conversion between `int` and `IntPtr`, so no luck there.

Generally, if you're going to be doing anything remotely complex with pointers, it's probably best to opt for unsafe code.

Comment: `IntPtr` is a .NET primitive type. Check `typeof(System.IntPtr).IsPrimitive`.

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking for. But maybe it's better to allocate a struct array and pass it as IntPtr; but I'm still wordering how guarantee that struct fields are aligned correctly...

Comment: Luca: `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout]` specifies alignment and packing parameters for a structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the integral memory address of the pointer structure using `IntPtr.ToInt32()` but beware of platform "bitness" (32/64).

For typical pointer arithmetics, use pointers (look up `fixed` and `unsafe` in the documentation):

```
T data = new T[count];
fixed (T* ptr = &data)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // now you can use *ptr + i or ptr[i]
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I'm pondering that `IntPtr` allows you to handle pointers to data without explicitly *manipulating* pointer addresses. This allows you to interop with COM and native code without having to declare unsafe contexts. The only requirement that the runtime imposes is the unmanaged code permission. For those purposes, it seems like most marshalling methods only accept whole `IntPtr` data, and not pure `integer` or `long` types, as it provides a thin layer that protects against manipulating the content of the structure. You *could* manipulate the internals of an `IntPtr` directly, but that either requires unsafe pointers (again unsafe contexts) or reflection. Finally, IntPtr is automatically adopted to the platform's pointer size.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.unsafeaddrofpinnedarrayelement?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get address of specific elements in an array using an `IntPtr` from a pinned array.

Here is a [sample class for a wrapper around pinned arrays](https://github.com/ara3d/ara3d-dev/blob/master/dotnet/Utilities/PinnedArray.cs) so that I can use them with IntPtr and Marshaling code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Pins an array of Blittable structs so that we can access the data as bytes. Manages a GCHandle around the array.
    /// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.unsafeaddrofpinnedarrayelement?view=netframework-4.7.2
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class PinnedArray<T> : IDisposable
    {
        public GCHandle Handle { get; }
        public T[] Array { get; }

        public int ByteCount { get; private set; }
        public IntPtr Ptr { get; private set; }

        public IntPtr ElementPointer(int n)
        {
            return Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(Array, n);
        }

        public PinnedArray(T[] xs)
        {
            Array = xs;
            // This will fail if the underlying type is not Blittable (e.g. not contiguous in memory)
            Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(xs, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            if (xs.Length != 0)
            {
                Ptr = ElementPointer(0);
                ByteCount = (int) Ptr.Distance(ElementPointer(Array.Length));
            }
            else
            {
                Ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
                ByteCount = 0;
            }
        }

        void DisposeImplementation()
        {
            if (Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Handle.Free();
                Ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
                ByteCount = 0;
            }
        }

        ~PinnedArray()
        {
            DisposeImplementation();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            DisposeImplementation();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

IMHO Working with PInvoke and IntPtr is as dangerous as marking your assembly as unsafe and using pointers in an unsafe context (if not more)

If you don't mind unsafe blocks you can write extension functions that operate on the `IntPtr` cast to `byte*` like the following:

```
    public static long Distance(this IntPtr a, IntPtr b)
    {
         return Math.Abs(((byte*)b) - ((byte*)a));
    }
```

However, like always you have to be aware of possible alignment issues when casting to different pointer types.